# GoogleAnalytics Block Override

Tags: magento2, override-block

Developer view, please

```
app/code/YourCompany/YourModule/etc/di.xml

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<!-- <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" type="Amf\GoogleAnalytics\Block\Catalog\Product\View" /> -->
<preference for="Magento\GoogleAnalytics\Block\Ga" type="YourCompany\YourModule\Block\Ga" />
```

Please let me know the best way

1. copy files from `vendor\magento\module-google-analytics\Block\Ga.php` then modify the method.
2. `vendor\magento\module-google-analytics\Block\Ga.php` - copy only required the method then do the modification.(code - https://textuploader.com/1a8x4)

Following point 1 error appears

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to Magento\GoogleAnalytics\Block\Ga::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in app\code\YourCompany\YourModule\Block\Ga.php on line 57 and defined in vendor\magento\module-google-analytics\Block\Ga.php on line 45
```

Following point 2 block override done - just override method getOrdersTrackingCode() and getOrdersTrackingData

The solution for the issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13827)